# ubuntu 18 save session not working

Tags: 18.04, desktop-environments, hibernate, ubuntu-gnome, dconf

I am using ubuntu 18, and need to be able to shutdown the pc, and keep the apps working for the next time I start the pc.

I've tried to allow hibernation and set up the shutdown button to hibernate, when I use it and turn the pc on, everything is closed, no application remain running.

I've tried to switch ["save gnome session"](https://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/remember-running-applications-ubuntu/) on, using the dconf editor, and still, no luck. I turned it on and nothing remains open when I shutdown the machine.

How can I get that results?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't from a normal Ubuntu since there is no save session as it is deemed a flawed feature and that is was not fixable. So it got removed in 2011: see [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/771896/comments/7) and [this](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2011-January/002734.html). But you can by using an extension. You will need this dependency:

```
npm install -g linux-window-session-manager
```

and then install Window Session Manager Gnome Shell extension from the [Gnome extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1323/window-session-manager/) website. From the link:

> An indicator that let's you save and restore your open apps and the window positions and arrangements over multiple real and virtual displays. Requires lwsm and nodejs to be installed (`npm install -g linux-window-session-manager`).
>
> [Extension Homepage](https://github.com/johannesjo/gnome-shell-extension-window-session-manager)

Comment: Will the os work the same after it? Will it be applicable for a regular desktop session or i will have to use anothet desktop?

Comment: this is not working, i've installed all of it and nothing happens, now I can't remove linux-window-session-manager, how to I remove it? tried using npm uninstall -g linux-window-session-manager and it's still there when I use npm ls -g | grep lunux-window-session-manager

Comment: update, when using sudo su and then removing, it works, but this is still not working for me, I need a way to keep the session and the instruction for installation are not working for me